# Way to find the element with the highest width

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, width

I have a webpage which has thousands of small elements, each with a different width and height.

What I want is to find the element with the highest width in a webpage via Chrome developer tools or Mozilla developer tools.

I can do it one by one by looking at the layout, but it will waste a lot of time.

[Chrome Developer's tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejdnh.jpg)

[Mozilla's developer's tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81nio.jpg)

Please help me by your experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have jQuery, you can do the following in the console of the Chrome Dev Tools:

```
var width = 0;
var element;
$('*').each(function() { 
    var element_width = $(this).width();
    if(element_width > width) {
        element = $(this);
        width = element_width;
    }
});
console.log(element);
console.log(element.width());
```

This code runs through all elements on the page, checks for the height and saves the one with the greatest height.

If you don't want to run over all elements, but rather over some child elements of an element, you can do the following:

```
var width = 0;
var element;
$('#myElement').children().each(function() { 
    var element_width = $(this).width();
    if(element_width > width) {
        element = $(this);
        width = element_width;
    }
});
console.log(element);
console.log(element.width());
```

And if your site doesn't have jQuery, you can insert it like that;

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Comment: It does for Height, can you please tell the procedure for width.?

Comment: Sorry to say, but its not working for width, it giving the value of height
and its not showing the element name as well

Comment: It gives you two results: `console.log(element)` prints the element to the console, `console.log(element.width());` prints the width of the element.

Comment: If it is showing the height in your case, make sure to replace every occurence of `height` with `width`. But the code above already uses the width.

Comment: please try it, i tried it not giving result for me.
everytime its showing 1530 for width for iphone 5 via developer tools.
it gives name of script not element.
Infact, the website in iphone 5 is not more than 340 px.

Please try for https://nepaltimes.net/

Comment: It doesn't give you the height, it gives you the width of a `script` tag, which is just some weird value, since it's not a usual html element with width and height. You can simply avoid that, by only inspecting elements in the body of the page: `$('body').children().each(function() { `